# Python Requests - pass parameter via GET

Tags: python, get, request, python-requests

I am trying to call an API and pass some parameters to it.

My endpoint should look like:  `https://example.com?q=food` (`food` is the parameter)

```
import requests
parametervalue = "food"
r = requests.get("https://example.com/q=", parametervalue)
```

When I do `print r.url`, I do not get the correct result - the value is not passed.

### Error:

```
  r = requests.get('https://example.com', params={'1':parametervalue})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
  return request('get', url, **kwargs)
```

### Update:

Answer posted below. Thank you.

**Note:** The SSL error mentioned in the post was due to me running Python 2.7. I used python 3 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Read the document first to save a significantly huge time... http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Seriously, in the very fisr page of the doc you can read in all letter "passing parameters in urls". Did you bother reading the doc at all ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't even bothered reading the doc.

Comment: I did. I get the errror:

Comment: r = requests.get('https://example.com', params={'1':parametervalue})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here's the relevant code to perform a GET http call from the [official documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
import requests
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

In order to adapt it to your specific request:

```
import requests
payload = {'q': 'food'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
print (r.text)
```

Here's the obtained result if I run the 2nd example:

```
python request_test.py
{"args":{"q":"food"},"headers":{"Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Connection":"close","Host":"httpbin.org","User-Agent":"python-requests/2.18.1"},"origin":"x.y.z.a","url":"http://httpbin.org/get?q=food"}
```

Comment: r = requests.get('https://example.com', params={'1':parametervalue})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)

Comment: I get it - thanx. I was also getting SSL errors because I was using Python2. Switching to 3 fixed the issue.