# How can i disable url encoding in request module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

How can i disable url encoding. This link working with curl but not working python3 request module.

Sample url: `https://api.bscscan.com/api\?module\=account\&action\=tokenbalance\&contractaddress\=0xf859Bf77cBe8699013d6Dbc7C2b926Aaf307F830\&address\=0x4e5680dd262cfb2568d286209250b7d5c776fcad\&tag\=latest\&apikey\=ASFDASDFASDFAWASDFSDFA`

"\" character is big problem

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737866/python-requests-pass-parameter-via-get).

Comment: it's definetly different

Comment: no, everything after `api` is to be passed as parameter.